# Collapse all class fields except comments

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any possible way to collapse all class fields except comments? Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O shortcut collapses all including comments.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find something interesting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507/give-me-awesome-visual-studio-keyboard-short-cuts). The second answer (not the one marked green) has a link to the [Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&DisplayLang=en) that might contain something of interest.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such shortcut in VS

Answer (score 0):

That task is a bit too specialized to a particular (keystroke-bindable) VS task.  However, it may not be too difficult to write as a DXCore addin.  (DXCore is the freely available engine that runs Developer's Express's CodeRush (DXCore can be found at http://www.devexpress.com)